# Install and Configure TigerVNC on macOS

Tags: macos, vnc, vncserver, tigervnc

I've been looking for a new VNC server and came across TigerVNC. I'm trying hard to read the documentation to install, it's totally command line based and I'm a bit stuck.

I've searched for others online, but only came across instructions for installing on linux/Ubuntu/redhat systems

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at [Homebrew](https://brew.sh), the package manager for MacOS?: `brew install tiger-vnc`